# Let $G$ be an abelian group. Define $G^{n}=\lbrace g^n :g \in G \rbrace$. Show that $G^n$ is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Define $G^{n}=\lbrace g^n :g \in G \rbrace$. Show that $G^n$ is a group. I mange to show that $G^n$ is closed under binary operation, associativity, contin identity. But I don know how to show it contains inverse for all elements. Anyone can guide me?

Comment: Do you know $(g^n)^{-1}=(g^{-1})^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Look at $f: G \to G$ with $f(g) = g^n$. Show that it is a homomorphism.

Otherwise for your way: You need to show that for every $g\in G$ there exists a $h\in G$ so that $g^n * h^n = 1$. Try to take $h = g^{-1}$ and use that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: So my working is like this : Since $G$ is a group, if $g \in G$ , then $g^{-1} \in G$. Hence, $g^{-n} \in G^n$. Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, then show that $(g^n)^{-1} = g^{-n}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\forall\,x\in G\;\;,\;\;\left(x^n\right)^{-1}=x^{-n}=\left(x^{-1}\right)^n$$

Further hint:

$$\forall\,x,y\in G\;\;,\;\;(xy)^k=x^ky^k\,\,,\,\,k\in\Bbb Z$$

Comment: You are always up Don.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of comments.

The point where the fact that $G$ is abelian enters is to prove that the product of two $n$-th powers is again an $n$-th power,
$$
g^n h^n = (g h)^n
$$
an identity that does not hold *in general* in a non-abelian group. (For instance, in $S_3$ the set of third powers has order $4$, and thus it is not a subgroup. But the set of squares is indeed the subgroup of order $3$.)

Without the assumption of $G$ being abelian, we have $1 = 1^n \in G^{n}$, and also if $g^n \in G^{n}$, then $(g^{n})^{-1} = (g^{-1})^{n} \in G^{n}$. This follows from the rule $(g^{a})^{b} = g^{ab}$ for powers.

But note that once you know that $G^{n}$ is closed with respect to the operation of the abelian group $G$, you do not have to show associativity. This is because you know $G$ to be a group, so $(ab)c = a(bc)$ for all $a, b c \in G$. So this [holds true in particular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_fortiori_argument) if $a, b, c$ are taken in the subset $G^{n}$ of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably ahead of what you know, but a simple proof follows from the fact that if $G$ is abelian then $g \mapsto g^n$ is a homomorphism, whose image is by definition $G^n$.