# Showing that $|G^n|$ is equal to $[G:G[n]]$

Tags: group-theory

This is part of exercise 2.55 of Rotman's Introduction to group theory. Let $G$ be a finite groupe. Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer, such that for all $x,y \in G$, $(xy)^n = x^ny^n$. If $G[n]=\{z\in G:z^n=1\}$ and $G^n=\{x^n:x\in G\}$. Show that $|G^n| = [G:G[n]]$. (I have already shown $G^n$ and $G[n]$ are normal subgroups of $G$).

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521797/let-g-be-an-abelian-group-and-let-a∈g-for-n≥1-let-gna-x∈gxn-a-show, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320385/let-g-be-an-abelian-group-define-gn-lbrace-gn-g-in-g-rbrace-show-t/320396#320396.

Comment: Not exactly, but it gave the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(xy)^n = x^ny^n$ for all $x,y\in G$, then $\phi: G \to G$ given by $\phi(x)=x^n$ is a homomorphism.

By definition,  $G[n]=\ker\phi$ and $G^n =\operatorname{im} \phi$.

By the isomorphism theorem, $G^n =\operatorname{im} \phi \cong G/\ker\phi =G / G[n]$ and so $|G^n| = [G:G[n]]$.

You can avoid the isomorphism theorem simply by noting that $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$ iff $xy^{-1} \in G[n]$, and so each element in $G^n$ has exactly $\left|G[n]\right|$ preimages.

Comment: How do you show that $G^n$ is a normal subgroup of G?