# Showing that $G^n$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

This is from exercise 2.55 "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups" by Joseph J. Rotman.

Let $G$ be a finite group, such that for some fixed integer $n>1$,for all $x,y\in G$, $(xy)^n = x^ny^n$. I need to prove that $G^n=\{x^n:x\in G\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I could prove that $G^n$ is a subgroup but i can't figure out the normal part.

Comment: Here's the link to the last part of this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584545/showing-that-gn-is-equal-to-ggn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in G^n$. For $h \in G$, consider $h^{-1}xh.$ Write $x=g^n$ for some $g$. Then $h^{-1} x h=h^{-1}g^nh =(h^{-1} g h)^n$ because all of the $h$ terms in the middle cancel. Hence, $h^{-1} x h\in G^n$, and so $G^n$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

We have, for any $g\in G$, $h=k^n\in G^n$ for $k\in G$, that

$$\begin{align}
ghg^{-1}&=gk^ng^{-1}\\
&=g\underbrace{k\dots k}_{n\text{ times}}g^{-1}\\
&=\underbrace{(gkg^{-1})\dots (gkg^{-1})}_{n\text{ times}}\tag{1}\\
&=(gkg^{-1})^n\\
&\in G^n,
\end{align}$$

where $(1)$ holds by inserting $e=g^{-1}g$ between the $k$s. Hence $ghg^{-1}\in G^n$.

Hence $G^n\unlhd G$.